# Creating .bvh from .c3d

Tags: motion-capture

I'm working on a project importing motion capture from physical therapy patients.  What I have been trying to do is import the .c3d data, creating an armature and parenting it to the .c3d, and exporting it as a .bvh.  My next step was to create a model via MakeHuman and map the .bvh to the model, but I am running into some issues here saying that some bones have multiple children.

Does anyone know of a different way to go about mapping the .c3d data to a model?  Is there an easier way to build the armature - I know the .bvh from the Carnegie Melon University works with Make human, should I try to build an armature that matches it exactly?

Open to any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: Enable the [motion capture tools](https://en.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Animation/Motion_Capture_Tools) addon that ships with blender, in the object properties you will get extras to retarget an animation to another armature.